# ListView - vertical scrollbar on left side

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

Is it possible to move ListView scroller to the left side?

Comment: Check my hack in the answer to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826879/how-to-make-the-scrollbar-appear-on-the-left-side/12527946#12527946

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move the scrollbar position to the left for any View using [`View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT).

Comment: I can't see View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT. I'm usin Google APIs 2.3.3

Comment: This Constant has been introduced in API level 11 (3.0.x). You can't use it out of the box with API level 9.

Comment: And how can I manage it out to get compatibility for older version?

Comment: You can extract the sources required to create your `ListView` from the AOSP, place it in your project and use this version of `ListView` instead of the one, that Android ships with.

Answer (score 0):

Try my dirty hack that seems to work at least on 2.2 and above:

[How to make the `scrollbar` appear on the left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826879/how-to-make-the-scrollbar-appear-on-the-left-side/12527946#12527946)