# Setting ListView scrollbar on the left, supporting API level 7

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

I'm extending the class `SherlockListFragment`

Inside this class I'm calling `getListView()` for retrieving the `ListView` related to my Fragment.

Below is shown the signature of the method `getListView()` that I'm using:

```
ListView android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView()
```

The problem is that I want call `setVerticalScrollbarPosition()` over this ListView, but my project has minSDK = 7, so the following code:

```
getListView().setVerticalScrollbarPosition(View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT);
```

gives me the error:

```
- Call requires API level 11 (current min is 7): 
     android.widget.ListView#setVerticalScrollbarPosition
```

How can I use this method, in order to work also in system with API level < 11 and > 7 ?

**NOTE:** I don't want use `@suppressLint`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to say that the code running inside the method is for API 11 and above

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void doVertScrollThingy() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getListView().setVerticalScrollbarPosition(View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT);
    } else {
        // do something else, because setVerticalScrollbarPosition isn't supported
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I want the same functionality for devices with API 7,8,9,10. I'm looking for some support library.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Try checking out this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826879/how-to-make-the-scrollbar-appear-on-the-left-side
A solution was posted, with no comments saying it worked, but you can try it. It involves extending `ListView`